# Redirect user once the login function is called

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to build a login functionality using angular; but I get reference error:

```
ReferenceError: $state is not defined
```

I understand *$state* is not working from inside login function but I am not sure what is the correct procedure to redirect user once login function is called.

My Code:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('authController', authController);

    authController.$inject = ['$scope','$state'];

    function authController($scope,$state) {

        $scope.login = login;
        $scope.user = {email: '', pass: ''};

    };

    function login(){
        this.dataLoading = true;

        $state.go("dashboard");     

    }       
})();
```

Comment: Just define `login()` function within `authController()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `login` function should be inside the controller context to get access the $state dependency which has been inject in controller function.

As you wanted to call `login` function from html, then its should be placed in controller only.

```
function authController($scope,$state) {

    $scope.login = login;
    $scope.user = {email: '', pass: ''};
    function login(){
       this.dataLoading = true;
       $state.go("dashboard");
    }  
    $scope.login = login; //to call method from html
};
```

**OR**

Still you wanted to place that function outside angular context for some technical reason(Ideally it shouldn't) then you could get access to `$state` service using `angular.injector`

```
angular.injector(['app']).get('$state').go("dashboard");
```

Comment: angular.injector() doesn't require module name??

Comment: First option is possible but I was hoping to get it done in login function; rather than bringing it back into main controller; the second option is hacky; maybe my logic is incorrect ?

Comment: @ArashKiani from where you are calling `login` method?

Comment: @PankajParkar from my view ng-submit="login()"

Comment: @ArashKiani so that should be there in controller, but it should also binded to controller scope;.

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly you are correct, it needs module name. I updated the answer..Thanks  for heads up..

Comment: @PankajParkar so I should somehow more the ng-submit=login into controller ? how can I do that ! can you give me a name of function of topic to google!

Comment: @PankajParkar sorry I noticed the modification right after i send the message; Its working fine now! great job thanks :)

Comment: Glad to help you..Thanks

Comment: @PankajParkar had no idea you can write function within function